# Validate given conditions across the rows in a database table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a database table with positions and coresponding values like this

```
position    value

Z170S11     630
Z176S11     103
Z060S11     7162
Z143S01     47
```

'position' is unique for this table. The set of positions is fixed. The row entries for column 'value' will change with each new run of the application.

I also have a fixed list of conditions across all the values in this table. This list is part of an Excel file that I want to store in my database. The list has entries like this

```
left hand side       operator    right hand side

Z143S01 + Z060S11    =           Z176S11     
Z143S01              >=          Z170S11
```

Both, left and right hand side may consist of sums and differences of up to 10 different values. Operators are '=', '<=' and '>='.

For each condition I need to check that the current 'value' fields are correct. E.g.

```
Z143S01 + Z060S11 = Z176S11
```

will evaluate to

```
47 + 7162 = 103
```

which is false. The result of each check should be presented to the user.

What is a good way to store these conditions as part of my database and automatically check if they are fulfilled with the given values from the table above?

I thought of storing them as string values in a table and evaluating each row individually using VBA's 'Split'- and 'DLookup'-functions. As I expect about 1.000 conditions to check, this might turn out too slow. Is there an easier/faster way, maybe relying more on SQL?

Comment: Can you provide more details

Comment: @VishalSheth what details are you thinking of? More example rows? I‘m open on the actual output format

Comment: @VishalSheth I updated the question and provided more details

Comment: Is it mandatory to go with SQL DLookup functions or is it good to go with some kind of script

Comment: Whatever works is good. The question is mainly about a good way to store the conditions as they will not change. I want the process to check them as clean as possible. A script splitting the string and using DLookups will probably get pretty messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom function opens a recordset of Positions, loops records and performs replace operation on condition expression string, Eval() function evaluates new string, returns a True or False.

```
Function TestVal(sStr As String)
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Positions")
Do While Not rs.EOF
    sStr = Replace(sStr, rs!Position, rs![Value])
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
Debug.Print sStr
TestVal = Eval(sStr)
End Function
```

Can call function in query or textbox.
`SELECT Conditions.*, TestVal([LeftSide] & [Operator] & [RightSide]) AS IsTrue FROM Conditions;`

Comment: This works great for me. It should be noted, that this solution assumes that every position that is part of a condition also has a value. If that is not the case the Eval will break. I could work around this by adding a 0 value for all positions. Thank you!

Comment: Or use Nz() or IIf() in query expression to force 0 if field is null.

Comment: Or deal with possible Null in the function. More than one way ...